# Converting decimals to [h]:mm:ss

Tags: excel, matlab, datetime, datetime-format

I'm importing data from Excel to MATLAB. My data in Excel is in `[h]:mm:ss` format, but when after importing to MATLABthe data becomes a decimal number.

Is there a way to convert this data back to an `[h]:mm:ss` format in MATLAB?

Some examples:

```
21:45:05 equals 0.906307870370370
21:14:31 equals 0.885081018518519
213:17:56 equals 8.88745370370370
```

I understand the conversion being a multiple of 24h be it in seconds, minuites or hours - which would imply 12:00:00 = 0.5. But I don't understand how I could convert the data back, i.e. 0.75 becomes 18:00:00 etc?

I've tried `New_Nun(i,j) = datestr(nun(i,j),'HH:MM:SS');` to do this conversion, but I get this error -

> Unable to perform assignment because the indices on the left side are not compatible with the size of the right side.

Would this be because my `nun` variable has `NaN`'s in?

Comment: I think the RHS of your command runs, but that gives a string, which I'd say does not fit in `New_Nun(i,j)`. Does the RHS run, and if so, what comes out?

Comment: @Adriaan that RHS runs - until i reach a NaN at which point it stops - so are you saying the definition for New_Nun needs to be changed to a Cell variable?

Comment: Ah, if it runs fine until it encounters a `NaN` value, just check for that and discard those, e.g. `nun(isnan(nun))=[]`

Comment: Note that you've used the wrong datetime format string... `HH:MM:SS` is `24hr hours : 2 digit month : 2 digit factional second`! You probably want something more like `HH:mm:ss`, read the documentation! Also note that Matlab's date numbers (the decimal value) is defined as " the number of days from January 0, 0000", I'm not sure if your Excel-imported data will correspond to this.

Comment: @Adriaan Done that via `isnan(nun(i,j)) == 0` and an if loop - although yours is a neater solution Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `datestr` outputs a string, while the `New_Nun(i,j)=...`assignment expects a single value.

`datestr(nun(i,j),'HH:MM:SS')` outputs a [8 x 1] char array, which will not fit into `New_Nun(i,j)`. And, by the way, `'HH:MM:SS'` is indeed the correct argument for hours, minutes and seconds.

You may rather use a cell for New_Nun, which can contain any kind of data including strings of arbitrary length :

```
%Initialize random values with a NaN
nun=rand([5 5]);
nun(2,5)=NaN;

New_Nun = cell(size(nun));  %Initialize the cell array
not_a_nan = ~isnan(nun);    %Selection valid values
New_Nun(not_a_nan) = cellstr(datestr(nun(not_a_nan),'HH:MM:SS')); %Fill the cell array

disp(New_Nun)    
'13:47:28'    '23:37:19'    '06:00:28'    '13:24:09'    '12:38:05'
'00:55:58'    '08:34:58'    '04:25:44'    '11:14:46'            []
'13:17:25'    '10:34:02'    '11:17:16'    '04:42:18'    '05:51:32'
'20:40:44'    '18:30:16'    '04:29:22'    '17:43:03'    '22:05:24'
'16:36:35'    '10:17:18'    '22:45:41'    '16:04:17'    '07:06:39'
```

The NaN value has been converted to an empty cell. It could be replaced with any default value, e.g. `New_Nun(~not_a_nan)={'00:00:00'};`

This code does not handle hours above 24, as datestr. For than, hours need to be treated separately.

```
%Initialize random values with a NaN and one value larger than 24h
nun=rand([5 5]);
nun(2,5)=NaN;
nun(3,4)=nun(3,4)+10;   % One value above 24h

New_Nun = cell(size(nun));  %Initialize the cell array
not_a_nan = ~isnan(nun);    %Selection valid values

mmss = cellstr(datestr(nun(not_a_nan),'MM:SS')); %Write only MM:SS
hh   = floor(nun(not_a_nan(:))*24); %Get hours, and make it a column vector

%Now, add the hours
hours_not_zero = hh~=0; % Optional: used to display mm:ss if hh=0
mmss(hours_not_zero) = cellfun(@(h,m) sprintf('%02d:%s',h,m),num2cell(hh(hours_not_zero)),mmss(hours_not_zero),'uniformoutput',false);


New_Nun(not_a_nan) = mmss;
disp(New_Nun)
'02:53:42'    '08:38:56'    '12:07:03'    '15:28:54'    '12:49:18'
'16:21:15'    '03:44:23'    '01:22:31'    '20:43'               []
'02:36:04'    '11:08:51'    '19:51:35'    '244:45:48'   '33:55'   
'16:14:08'    '08:04:01'    '12:27:22'    '08:17:48'    '06:16:15'
'10:41:08'    '03:16:19'    '04:47:15'    '04:33:37'    '20:36:42'
```

This time, the value 35:34:11 is represented correctly. Not significant hours are not displayed, such as '20:43' for '00:20:43'.